Why does my 3D UNet always predict black when doing binary segmentation?
My input images are grayscale images (uint8) and the target images are binary images (bool). I convert the input images to 0~1 and normalize them before feeding them into a 3D UNet.
Here is the code I used for 3D UNet model.
Here is my code for training:
unet = UNet3D(in_channels=1, num_classes=1).to(device)

bce_loss = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(unet.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0005)

for epoch in range(args.epochs):
    unet.train()
    train_loss = 0.0
    for step, (x, y_true, _) in enumerate(train_loader):  
        x, y_true = x.to(device=device, dtype=torch.float), y_true.to(device=device, dtype=torch.float)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        y_pred = unet(x)  # y_pred - (batch_size,1,depth,width,height)

        loss = bce_loss(y_pred, y_true)  # y_true - (batch_size,1,depth,width,height)
        train_loss += loss.item()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        print("Epoch %d, average training cross entropy loss %9.6f" % (epoch + 1, train_loss / len(train_loader)))

My binary cross entropy loss does not converge to a small number. The maximum value of prediction cannot go beyond 0.5 so that I cannot predict the masks.
I tried to use different learning rate, changed loss function to bce loss + dice loss, but still it does not work.
